# How to install Asterisk on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, server, asterisk

I want to install Asterisk server on Ubuntu 11.10. Is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial [here](http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/how-to-install-asterisk-1-8-on-ubuntu-server-11-04/) which uses a slightly out of date version of Asterisk. It is for Ubuntu server 11.04.

The latest version of Asterisk is listed [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions). (Currently 1.8.x for Long Term Support till 2015-10-21 or the newer 10.x supported until 2013-12-15.)

You can use the [newest version](http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/releases/), currently 10.4.1 by replacing `asterisk-1.8.4` with `asterisk-10.4.1` in the following commands:

```
apt-get install build-essential libxml2-dev ncurses-dev 
wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/releases/asterisk-1.8.4.tar.gz
tar zxvf asterisk-1.8.4.tar.gz  
cd asterisk-1.8.4/
./configure
make 
make install 
make config 
make samples
```

Comment: this doesn't say anything about finding the ton of audio codec development libraries required for asterisk to work